# How to set Inset on toolbar items globally?

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have tried this from AppDelegate, but the tabBarController is at that point nil and it won't work.

```
self.window?.rootViewController?.tabBarController?.toolbarItems![0].imageInsets.top = 5.0
self.window?.rootViewController?.tabBarController?.toolbarItems![1].imageInsets.top = 5.0
```

I could do that for the first tabbar item only by inserting this piece of code in the first view controller:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarItem.imageInsets.top = 5.0
}
```

But I can't apply this to the second view controller, as it's not loaded until the user clicks on the tab bar item in the first place.

Comment: The following is syntactically correct - will it work? (I placed this where I place all my global UI styling - AppDelegate.) `UITabBarItem.appearance().imageInsets.top = 5.0`

Answer (score 1):

So you can create your own class of UITabBarController:

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        if let tabBarItems = self.tabBar.items {
            for item in tabBarItems {
                item.imageInsets.top = 5
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then in storyboard set this class as custom of your UITabBarController

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that this is too late:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.tabBarItem.imageInsets.top = 5.0
}
```

The place to prepare your view controller's tab bar item is in its initializer. You'll need to override `init(coder:)` (assuming that this view controller instance comes from the storyboard):

```
required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder:aDecoder)
    self.tabBarItem.imageInsets.top = 5.0
}
```